# How to change the useragent of Inet Control?

Tags: vb6, user-agent, inet

I tried to set the usergent using

```
Inet1.Execute , "GET", "Referer: yahoo.com" & vbCrLf & "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" & vbCrLf & "Accept-Language: en-us" & vbCrLf & "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" & vbCrLf & "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatiable; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; yie6)"
```

but it didnt't work :(

Any solution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426198/error-when-using-microsoft-internet-transfer-control-6-0 for a possible alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user agent is not something that you can set.  You are using the Microsoft Internet Transfer control so the user agent will be "Microsoft URL Control - (some version number)".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set the User-Agent for the Inet control. The requester is on the right track - but instead of the 'data' arg use the 'requestHeaders' arg.

Answer (score 0):

'WebBrowser1.Navigate "yoursitegoeshere.com/", , , , "User-Agent: User Agent Goes Here"

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer.